# How did Mysterio "beat up" Peter Parker?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In the scene below from *Spider-Man:  Far From Home*, Mysterio uses the Stark drones to create an illusion in order to attack Peter. At 1:42, multiple Spider-Men are attacking Peter: he obviously is able to feel the pain, like if this was a real attack. How do the drones attack him like this, as neither the lasers nor the repulsor tech would cause this effect?

Comment: Who says repulsors can't do that? It's clear that they are the only ones who could.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is repulsors the answer?

Comment: What else.... it's obviously the drones causing the effect, everything else is holograms

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! I've made it an answer and credited you. Please edit if I got it wrong. Or make your own and I'll vote for yours and delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repulsor tech caused the effect. Credit to the [comments of Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118157/how-did-mysterio-beat-up-peter-parker#comment206628_118157):

> Who says repulsors can't do that? It's clear that they are the only ones who could.

> What else.... it's obviously the drones causing the effect, everything else is holograms